# How to load .xlsx file and display its data?

Tags: reactjs, parsing, fetch

I was practicing how to fetch data from xlsx file. I have been watching different videos and tutorials. But couldn't figure out how to modify this sample code. I am trying to modify this sample code to display the data from the .xlsx file without the use of the upload option. I just wanted to see the data displayed on the screen when I run the file instead of choosing the file to upload.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const readExcel = (file) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;
        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
        resolve(data);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });

    promise.then((d) => {
      setItems(d);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          const file = e.target.files[0];
          readExcel(file);
        }}
      />

      <table className="table container">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Agent</th>
            <th scope="col">Property_type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {items.map((d) => (
            <tr key={d.agent}>
              <th>{d.agent.steve}</th>
              <td>{d.property_type}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is therre an error appear when you run this? also, silly suggestion, can you try to move `readAsArrayBuffer` after `onload` and `onerror` definitions?

Comment: It perfectly works. But like I said that's not what I needed.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, I read it multiple times but I'm still not sure what are you looking for. Is it that you want a button to load the excel file content after selecting file instead of showing the content directly on selecting?

Comment: I don't want a button. I just wanted the table to be displayed by default without having a button.